# What if speed of air exceeds 340m/s?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, acoustics, speed, air

We know that Mach cones are formed when an object moves faster than the speed of sound. This creates huge noise in the surroundings.

[image]

Here the airplane is moving faster than sound relative to stationary air around, creating a trailing Mach cone.

But **if the air itself is moving at a speed higher than 340m/s, then will every stationary object act as a source of Mach cone?**
If it is true then will that place be overwhelming with all the noises created by Mach cones.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How can air move faster than sound since it is the very propagation medium of sound? Do you mean air moving faster than 300m/s?

Comment: Yeah, air moving faster than 300m/s.
Sorry for that

Comment: Unlike the speed of light, acoustic media can indeed move faster than their sound speed.  In fact, since the speeds in question are all much lower than the speed of light, you can use Galilean relativity just fine, and you can interpret the air as stationary and all surrounding objects as flying past, regardless of what a ground observer would see the air speed as.

Comment: An example situation where the speed of the air could exceed the speed of sound would be a supersonic jet (such as those that exit rocket engines).

Comment: @Winston - there are supersonic wind tunnels. One needs them to study supersonic aerodynamics.

Comment: @Jon Custer: you did not understand my point.

Answer (score 1):

If some part of the air moves faster than the speed of sound, then the air itself acts like a piston to compress the air and the density of the compressed region increases. If the air moves much faster than the speed of sound, then the air can be compressed a lot so that the sound wave can make a thin and spike-like wave, which is called shock wave. Here, by spike-like I meant the thermodynamic properties of the air in the compressed region is very different from that of the air nearby, for example, number density, temperature, pressure, and etc. The shock wave thus generated is stable enough to travel long distances and carries huge amount of energy compared to normal sound wave.